# Lazy evaluation on templated function parameter

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I have a class for logging, which MUST NOT inherit std::ostream, and has operator<< defined for the same types as the standard output stream PLUS a templated version:

```
class MyLoggingClass {
[...]
public:
    template<typename T> MyLoggingClass & operator<<( T& data ){ ... }
}
```

Also, for every printable class in my program, I have the typical non-member function defined:

```
std::ostream & operator << ( std::ostream & os, const OneOfMyClasses & foo );
```

The thing is that, internally, my logger sometimes uses an standard output stream, this is:

```
template<typename T>
MyLoggingClass & operator<<( T& data )
{
    [...]
    if( someCondition )
    {
        cout << data;
    }
    [...]
}
```

Thanks to this, I can log my classes without explicitly replicating on every of them the non-member operator<< for MyLoggingClass.
The problem comes in a line where I try to log an object created "on the fly":

```
MyLoggingClass logger;
logger << OneOfMyClasses(params); // Here I am invoking the constructor of class "OneOfMyClasses"
```

The thing is that, instead of invoking the constructor, and then passing the object as parameter of the operator<<, it interprets that I'm trying to log a pointer to function.

Of course, some valid solutions for this problem include:

- Removing the templated operator<<, and making MyLoggingClass extend std::ostream
- Removing the templated operator<<, and creating tons of non-member operator<<( MyLoggingClass &, const OneOfMyClasses & )
- Storing the object to log in a temporal variable, and then doing "logger << temporalObject;"
  However, I would like to know if there is a way to force the compiler evaluating the constructor call. Do you know any workaround for this case?

Thank you in advance for your time :)

Comment: Could it be solved by extra parentheses around the constructor? I.e. `logger << (OneOfMyClasses(params));`

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention it. No, It doesn't work :S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is the problem is:

```
template<typename T> MyLoggingClass & operator<<( T& data ){ ... }
```

`data` is non-const reference and the line:

```
logger << OneOfMyClasses(params);
```

is attempting to bind a temporary to a non-const reference.

Change to:

```
template<typename T> MyLoggingClass & operator<<(const T& data ){ ... }
                                               //^^^^^
```

Comment: You are right: it was the const-thing. One of the problems of dealing with "legacy code" --apart from the cascade of const-related errors I had to fix after adding the qualifier.